# How to impose synstactic constraints in apriori in Orange

Tags: constraints, data-mining, orange

I use orange to build association rules on medical sparse dataset. But I can't find a way to insert syntactic constraints in rules production?

Seems that in Orange I can only choose: min support, min confidence and max number of rules, but I'm interested to have a specific set of event on the right or on the left side of the implications.

For example, I be interested only in rules that have a specific item I(x) appearing in the consequent, or rules that have a specific item I(y) appearing in the antecedent, or combinations of the above constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Rules are usually not generated as rules, but as **frequent item sets**.

To derive association rules, you need to know the support of every possible *subset*, too. Computing and storing these subsets is the challenge. Extracting the rules from the FIMs is not very difficult or expensive.

So you may as well apply the constraints only to the input data, or output rules after generation. If you apply the rules too early or in the wrong place, you may violate the monotonicity requirements required to have a correct result.

Comment: so if I have a dataset with 20 attributes and I’m interested in exploring the rules derived from FIMs containing a specific attribute you advise me to remove from the dataset all transactions that do not contain the specific attribute so it appears certainly among the FIMs? It’s right?

Comment: You need to double-check the exact conditions when you can do this. I believe this only works for the antecedent side. Make sure to understand the math and the monotinicity property.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the latest [Orange 3](http://orange.biolab.si/). There seems to be an updated [Orange3-Associate add-on](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Orange3-Associate) available (installable via menu: *Options > Add-ons*) that seems to do exactly what you ask for, namely that you can filter induced itemsets/rules by number of items and/or regular expressions.